# How to Change Scene in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I am Developing a game in AndEngine Gles2. I have splash scene, loading scene, menu scene and Level1 scene. I am using a Screen Manager to manage all scenes through which i can easily switch between splash, loading and menu scene, the level1 scene is also loaded from menu perfectly but problem occur when i go back to menu scene on the completion of level, screen turned to black and nothing shown after that. I think the problem is with unloading the resources of Level1 because the switching between other scene is perfect. I can't give complete code, as it is to much lengthy.

I am using bitmapTexture region, Sprites, bodies, physics Word, hud and fixtures etc.
here is my unload method..
1 more thing when i loaded the menu scene at the end of level 1 screen turn to black, but the music played and all logs are showed in logcat which i set in menu scene.

```
unload(){
setChildrenIgnorUpdate();
clearChildScene();
clearEntityModifier();
clearTouchAreas();
clearUpdateHandler();
BitmapTextureManager.getInstance().destroyInstance();
destroyPhysics();
}
```

Please Any help...

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here

```
BitmapTextureManager.getInstance().destroyInstance();
```

are you re-initializing the texture resources when your go back to the menu scene? Because it sounds as if everything is working but your textures are destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

I think unloading of texture creates problem for you.

As per my opinion load all graphics of the game at the time of loading scene. Then don't unload the graphics. I want to say that only game scene graphics which is changing per level that only need to unload and load it again.

Don't unload all graphics and load it again. Only load once which are fix for the game and keep in graphics memory of the device.

Overflowing of graphic memory creates this type of abnormal behaviour.